# How does touch -t work internally?

Tags: files, date, timestamps

How does `touch -t` command works exactly, internally (I tried to find its source code but couldn't)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`touch` calls the [`utimes`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=utimes&sektion=2) system call to set the file's modification time and its access time. On some systems, instead of `utimes`, it opens the file and then sets the file times through the descriptor, e.g. with [`utimensat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/utimensat) under Linux.

You can see how `touch` works on your system by looking at the system calls it makes. Under Linux, use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), e.g. `strace touch -d '1 hour ago' foo`.

Where to find the source code depends on your operating system. The GNU version is in [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), there's a version in the main source tree of any BSD, there's a version in [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/), in [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/), etc.

Answer (score 30):

Sometimes you don't even need the source code. Use `strace`.

```
$ strace touch -t 201212121212 foobar
execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "-t", "201212121212", "foobar"], [/* 61 vars */]) = 0
[...] lots of noise [...]
open("foobar", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
utimensat(0, NULL, {{1355310720, 0}, {1355310720, 0}}, 0) = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Why hello there, `utimensat()`. What are you?

```
$ man utimensat

NAME
   utimensat, futimens - change file timestamps with nanosecond precision
```

So there's a function that changes file timestamps, and `touch` uses it to update a file's timestamp. And that's how it works internally.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how it works on Solaris. `truss` is used instead of `strace` which is quite a different command here.

Like under Gnu/Linux, `utimensat` is the system call used.

```
$ truss -vall -u a.out -f touch -t 1306080000 z
4160:   execve("/usr/bin/touch", 0xF0770FC0, 0xF0770FD4)  argc = 4
...
4160/1@1:       -> main(0x4, 0xf0770fc0, 0xf0770fd4, 0xf0770f7c)
...
4160/1@1:           -> atoi_for2(0xf0771131, 0x0, 0x24, 0xebc95be0)
4160/1@1:           <- atoi_for2() = 13
4160/1@1:           -> atoi_for2(0xf0771133, 0x0, 0x24, 0xebc95be0)
4160/1@1:           <- atoi_for2() = 6
4160/1@1:           -> atoi_for2(0xf0771135, 0x0, 0x24, 0xebc95be0)
4160/1@1:           <- atoi_for2() = 8
4160/1@1:           -> atoi_for2(0xf0771137, 0x0, 0x24, 0xebc95be0)
4160/1@1:           <- atoi_for2() = 0
4160/1@1:           -> atoi_for2(0xf0771139, 0x0, 0x24, 0xebc95be0)
4160/1@1:           <- atoi_for2() = 0
4160/1@1:         <- parse_time() = 0x51b257e0
4160/1:         stat64("z", 0xF0770ED0)                         = 0
4160/1:             d=0x08A00002 i=75783706 m=0100644 l=1  u=100   g=10    sz=0
4160/1:                 at = Jun  8 01:48:08 CEST 2013  [ 1370648888.022270973 ]
4160/1:                 mt = Jun  8 01:48:08 CEST 2013  [ 1370648888.022270973 ]
4160/1:                 ct = Jun  8 01:48:08 CEST 2013  [ 1370648888.022273810 ]
4160/1:             bsz=4096  blks=0     fs=tmpfs
4160/1:         utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "z", 0xF0770F60, 0)         = 0
4160/1:                 at = Jun  8 00:00:00 CEST 2013  [ 1370642400.000000000 ]
4160/1:                 mt = Jun  8 00:00:00 CEST 2013  [ 1370642400.000000000 ]
4160/1@1:       <- main() = 0
4160/1@1:       -> _fini()
4160/1@1:       <- _fini() = 0xebcc0140
4160/1:         _exit(0)
```